# Find Broken Reference path in script task C# SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

In SSIS script task i would like to find out what the path is that the Reference is trying to point to so that I can fix it by putting the DLL in the right path. I would not like to change the path on my local dev machine since there are servers i need to send it to that is already referencing the right path where it works on the server. How do i see what the right path is of a broken reference for a third part tool?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy all reference to Global assemble cache , in order to run your SSIS package.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly
```

In run time, all reference  DLL will fetch from above location.

You can use this command (you may need to run it through VS command prompt) to install DLL into the GAC

```
gacutil -i "[dll path]"
```

Comment: The DLL is working on the server in the ...\100\DTS\Binn folder but i do not see it anywhere in the GAC

Answer (score 1):

Using hiran nuwanga's answer and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac) I discovered that the answer is indeed to install using gacutils into the assembly. so all I had to do was run the following command : gacutil -i "C:\MyDLL.dll"

Then everything works fine.

Comment: If Hiran provided the answer, you should mark the answer as the answer.

Comment: will do @KeithL